# adding new attributes using moose

Tags: perl, moose

I recently learned about [`Moose`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose).  When I create a new attribute in a subclass, it seems to somehow override other functions that should be working...

```
use strict; use warnings;

################################### VEHICLE ####################################
package Vehicle;

sub new{
    my $classname = shift;
    bless { wheels=>'unknown', color=>'unknown', @_ } => $classname
}

sub wheels{
    my $vehicle = shift;
    return $$vehicle{wheels}
}

sub setWheels{
    my $vehicle = shift;
    $$vehicle{wheels} = $_[0];
}

##################################### CAR ######################################

package Car;
use Moo; extends 'Vehicle';

sub new{
    my $classname = shift;
    my $vehicle = vehicle->new( @_ );
    $vehicle->setWheels(4);
    bless $vehicle => $classname
}

has 'spoiler' => ( is=>'rw', reader=>'rspoil', writer=>'setSpoiler' );

1
```

The issue is that when I create a Car object, it does not have 4 wheels.  It has 'unknown' wheels.  If I comment out the "has 'spoiler' => ..." statement at the bottom, it works just fine.

What is causing the issue?

What is the recommended way to do what I am doing?

Comment: You're not using [Moose attributes](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Manual::Attributes) at all, which is probably what you should be doing.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, if you're writing a class using Moose, you should **never define your own method called `new`**. See [Moose best practices](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/BestPractices.pod#Never-override-new).

Secondly, if you're using Moose to extend a non-Moose class, you probably want to use [MooseX::NonMoose](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX%3a%3aNonMoose) which is able to make that all work pretty smoothly.

Answer (score 3):

Moo bakes in the extending non-Moo classes. Assuming that for your example you're working with a Vehicle class that isn't yours, but trying to write the child class in Moo, here's how to do it.

In Moo*, you don't declare a new. It handles that for you. You can mutate state by declaring a BUILD subroutine - this will get run after instantiation on the instantiated object from parent to child. Thus:

```
use strict; use warnings;

################################### VEHICLE ####################################
package Vehicle;

sub new{
    my $classname = shift;
    bless { wheels=>'unknown', color=>'unknown', @_ } => $classname
}

sub wheels{
    my $vehicle = shift;
    return $$vehicle{wheels}
}

sub setWheels{
    my $vehicle = shift;
    $$vehicle{wheels} = $_[0];
}

##################################### CAR ######################################

package Car;
use Moo; extends 'Vehicle';

sub BUILD {
    my $self = shift;
    if ($self->wheels eq 'unknown') {
        $self->setWheels(4);
    }
}

has 'spoiler' => ( is=>'rw', reader=>'rspoil', writer=>'setSpoiler' );

package Main;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;

p(Car->new(spoiler => 'big', color => 'bright red'));

my $strangecar = Car->new(spoiler => 'piddly', color => 'yellow', wheels => 3);
p($strangecar);
$strangecar->setWheels(6);
$strangecar->setSpoiler('not so piddly');
p($strangecar);
```

**Output**

```
Car  {
    Parents       Vehicle
    public methods (4) : BUILD, new, rspoil, setSpoiler
    private methods (0)
    internals: {
        color     "bright red",
        spoiler   "big",
        wheels    4
    }
}
Car  {
    Parents       Vehicle
    public methods (4) : BUILD, new, rspoil, setSpoiler
    private methods (0)
    internals: {
        color     "yellow",
        spoiler   "piddly",
        wheels    3
    }
}
Car  {
    Parents       Vehicle
    public methods (4) : BUILD, new, rspoil, setSpoiler
    private methods (0)
    internals: {
        color     "yellow",
        spoiler   "not so piddly",
        wheels    6
    }
}
```

To use Moo for both parent and child, you would do:

```
use strict; use warnings;

################################### VEHICLE ####################################
package Vehicle;
use Moo;

has 'wheels' => ( is=>'rw', writer=>'setWheels', default => sub { 'unknown' });
has 'color' => (is => 'rw', default => sub { 'unknown' });

##################################### CAR ######################################

package Car;
use Moo; extends 'Vehicle';

has 'spoiler' => ( is=>'rw', reader=>'rspoil', writer=>'setSpoiler' );
has '+wheels' => ( default => sub {4} );

package Main;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;

p(Car->new(spoiler => 'big', color => 'bright red'));

my $strangecar = Car->new(spoiler => 'piddly', color => 'yellow', wheels => 3);
p($strangecar);
$strangecar->setWheels(6);
$strangecar->setSpoiler('not so piddly');
p($strangecar);
```

Which yields similar output to the above code.